# Different encryption Android JVM vs Desktop JVM - RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, jvm

I have a java application running on a server, in which i have implemented an encryption/decryption mechanism using RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding .
As a client i have made a Java implementation that takes an String input, encrypt it with the same algorithm, using a public key generated by the server application.
The problem that i'm facing is that this client Java implementation works so fine in a desktop JVM, but it generates this error in the server (`Exception ERROR: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: lHash mismatch`
) when encrypting in an android application.
Is there a difference between encryption in desktop JVM and encryption in Android JVM ?

Comment: you should post a minimal code example demonstrating the issue

Comment: Do you encrypt the same message and the same key? RSA has a maximum message size depending on the bitsize of the used RSA key. If your message is getting too long it will fail.

Comment: Have you found any solution?